# Unable to compare string received from tcp VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, tcp, string-comparison

I am working on an application that receives a string via tcp. I then parse the string using a deliminator.

Everything works fine up till this point. However I want to do a simple if statement with string comparison on the parsed results.

Each result has two parameters, the imagePath and imageID. If the imageID is not NULL I want to perform some action. However, even when I receive imageID with the value NULL the action within the if statement is triggered.

This is an example of the string that I receive and parse:

```
V:/Movies/Pic010.jpg=59289|V:/Movies/Pic011.jpg=59318|V:/Movies/Pic012.jpg=59278|V:/Movies/Pic04.jpg=59256|V:/Movies/Pic05.jpg=59351|V:/Movies/Pic07.jpg=59267|V:/Movies/Pic08.jpg=59307|V:/Movies/Pic09.jpg=59340|V:/Movies/longWaydown.png=59374|V:/Movies/mali.png=59329|V:/Pic010.jpg=NULL|V:/Pic011.jpg=NULL|V:/Pic03.jpg=NULL|V:/Pic04.jpg=NULL
```

this is the parsing code with the if statement that is causing the problems:

```
Dim imagesStatus As New Hashtable
    Dim tempImagesArray As String()
    tempImagesArray = imagesStatusString.Split("|")

    For Each img In tempImagesArray
        Dim imagePath As String = img.Remove(img.IndexOf("="))
        Dim imageID As String = img.Substring(img.IndexOf("=") + 1)
        imagesStatus(imagePath) = imageID
    Next

    Try
        Dim tempMovieQue As New List(Of String)
        For Each movieAsset In currentMovieAssets.Values
            Dim imageID As String = imagesStatus(graphicAssetsBasePath & "/" & movieAsset("poster").ToString)
            imageID = imageID.Trim()

            If Not imageID = "NULL" Then // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                Console.WriteLine(imageID)
                tempMovieQue.Add("{{imageID} {" & imageID & "} {genre} {" & movieAsset("genre") & "} {special} {" & movieAsset("special") & "} {title} {" & movieAsset("asset") & "}}")
            End If
        Next
```

When I run debugging and inspect the imageID value, it receives the value "NULL" therefore I am unable to understand why my if statement fails.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if not imageID is DBNull.Value Then
```

.Net is picky about null values, and they want you to have the Is comparison instead of =